# JPA One To Many PK Returns Null (Persist)

Tags: java, jpa, persist

I'm trying to create a new record in a One-to-Many relationship using JPA. I keep getting a 'javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted' exception.
Upon debugging I found the Author object I'm working with does not return the primary key and therefore can not set the 'AuthorID' in its' respective Book Collection object.

Ive tried this

```
author = new Author();
book = new Book();
Collection<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();

author.setAuthorFirstName(request.getParameter("authorFirstName"));
author.setAuthorLastName(request.getParameter("authorLastName"))
authorService.create(author);
//authorService.flush();

book.setTitle(title);
book.setDatePublished(sdf.parse(userEnteredDate));
book.setAuthorID(author);
list.add(book);
author.setBookCollection(list);

authorService.edit(author);
```

And I've also tried this:

```
author = new Author();
book = new Book();
Collection<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();   

author.setAuthorFirstName(request.getParameter("authorFirstName"));
author.setAuthorLastName(request.getParameter("authorLastName"));
authorService.create(author);
authorService.flush();
Author author2 = authorService.edit(author);
book.setTitle(title);
book.setDatePublished(sdf.parse(userEnteredDate));
book.setAuthorID(author2);
list.add(book);
author2.setBookCollection(list);
authorService.edit(author2);
```

And the Facade:

```
 public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
 private Class<T> entityClass;

 public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
 }

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public T edit(T entity) {
    return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}

public void flush(){
    getEntityManager().flush();
}

public void refresh(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
}
```

}

I've read through all the other similar questions posted on this site and several others and none of the techniques seem to be working. Can someone please explain why the AuthorID is not being retrieved?

Comment: What is `authorService.create()` doing?  Neither of the example blocks show the `Author` being persisted, so I assume that's something your `create()` method does?  If you're using autogenerated PK values then of course your object will not return a valid PK until after it has been persisted by the `EntityManager`.

Comment: create() = persist()
That's the terminology netbeans uses in a one-to-many scenario.
If it were a single table and a single object it would use persist().

Comment: I'm unclear how you mean.  Netbeans is just an IDE, is it not?  It may be generating some code for you according to whatever conventions it prefers, however if you're using JPA then regardless of anything Netbeans does somewhere there _must_ be an `EntityManager` instance and there also _must_ be code that that uses it to `persist()` a newly created entity.

Comment: check out the facade I just posted. The entity manager is there in each of the methods.